# sql server error messages

Tags: sql-server

let's say i have a trigger which tries to update a non existing table.
does sql server out of the box logs these kind of things somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any errors should go into the [SQL Server Error Log](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187109%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx).

Comment: amazing, never looked at that before [shame]